# Change Date Format

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the UI DatePicker from jQuery UI as the standalone picker. I have this code:

And I'm using this code for getting a selected date

```
select: function (selectedDate) {

     $("#customer1").show();
          $("#selected-date").text(selectedDate);

      },
```

It's working perfect but not in correct format.

It's showing "Wed Jun 14 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000
" in this format but I want like 14/06/2017.

Please help me to get in this format dd/mm/yy

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your search for an answer? This has been answered multiple times over and over again

Comment: Yes Carsten I'm sue, almost i used every code but result are same. Can you please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

Set it on intalization with:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

or set it this way:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
$("#selected-date").text(selectedDate);
```

Comment: It's working perfect #Remling but wherever i click it showing only Today's date and I want like selected date. Suppose if i select date 15/06/2017 then it will show 15/06/2017 not 30/06/2017.

Comment: I used this code and it's working absoulitly perfect :)

select: function ( selectedDate) {
                      $("#customer1").show();
                      var selectedDate = moment(selectedDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY");                      
                      $("#selected-date").text(selectedDate);
                  }

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it's working absolutely perfect :)

select: function ( selectedDate) {

```
                  $("#customer1").show();
                  var selectedDate = moment(selectedDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY");                      
                  $("#selected-date").text(selectedDate);
              }
```